# Getting parent title when crawling child pages using nutch

Tags: nutch

When crawling a website say www.example.com has a page x.html which has outlinks of 4 childs ,if process the the links i am getting the x.html title for all the 4 child pages.

In which case, we add parent title to child in nutch?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a HTMLParseFilter and add a custom metadata ([see JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1622)) to the outlinks with the title of the main page as value.

BTW you'd get a more relevant audience by posting on the [Nutch user list](http://nutch.apache.org/mailing_lists.html)